# Extract detected faces in DlibDotNet

Tags: c#, .net-core, face-detection, dlib

I'm using DlibDotNet and I'm new in it. I have the following code from [Detect Faces With C# And Dlib In Only 40 Lines Of Code](https://medium.com/machinelearningadvantage/detect-faces-with-c-and-dlib-in-only-40-lines-of-code-f0bb1b929133):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // set up Dlib facedetector
            using (var fd = Dlib.GetFrontalFaceDetector())
            {
                var img = Dlib.LoadImage<RgbPixel>(inputFilePath);

                // find all faces in the image
                var faces = fd.Operator(img);
                foreach (var face in faces)
                {
                    // draw a rectangle for each face
                    Dlib.DrawRectangle(img, face, color: new RgbPixel(0, 255, 255), thickness: 4);
                }
                Dlib.SaveJpeg(img, "output.jpg");
            }
        }
```

The question is that how can I extract all the faces detected in image?
I've tested `Dlib.ExtractImageChips()` Method but I don't know how to use it correctly.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What means 'all the faces'?

Comment: You could use the xy,topleft from face and crop the image for each face

Comment: @villageTech I mean human faces. it's a face detection code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the method after diging into the library. Here is the implementation:

```
DPoint[] dPoint = new DPoint[] {
                    new DPoint(face.TopLeft.X, face.TopLeft.Y),
                    new DPoint(face.TopRight.X, face.TopRight.Y),
                    new DPoint(face.BottomLeft.X, face.BottomLeft.Y),
                    new DPoint(face.BottomRight.X, face.BottomRight.Y),
                };
                    int width = (int)dRectangle.Width;
                    int height = (int)dRectangle.Height;

                    img = Dlib.ExtractImage4Points(img, dPoint, width, height);
```

Where img is the source image, dPoint is an array of four point that represent four corners of extracted piece of image an width and height are size of extracted image in pixles.

Answer (score 1):

After using Dlib.GetFaceChipDetails() and Dlib.ExtractImageChips() you should be getting face images from a given image, just need to convert as Bitmap. To convert
Array2D to Bitmap, you should be added DlibDotNet.Extensions DLL latest version in your project. Code looks like

```
List<Image> images = new List<Image>();

using (var faceChips = Dlib.ExtractImageChips<RgbPixel>(img, chipLocations))
{
    Image image = null;
    //Iterate face chips and add image one by one if multiple images existed
    foreach (var face in faceChips)
    {
        image = face.ToBitmap();
        images.Add(image);
    }
}
```

[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/KingCobrass/face.image.extractor) where shown how to extract face images from an image file.